# Nothing happens when importing cert to keychain in Mac Mojave

Tags: ssl, keychain, macos-mojave

I have a container running locally. My Apache server has a self signed certificate that I am trying to load to my Mac's keychain and I get no errors but the certificate just does not show up. I can open https://localhost on a Chrome browser and I can skip the warnings that the certificate is untrusted but I cannot use tools like Postman as the requests are blocked.

Any idea why this may be happening?

This is the steps I followed:

- Opened https://localhost in Chrome. Clicked on the lock and dragged and dropped the cert to my desktop
- Opened Key Chain and selected "System"
- I went to File -> Import new items and selected the cert that I grabbed from the browser

No errors but the cert just does not show up on the list at all.

I am using Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Try the following approach: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-and-update-keychain-access-on-macos/